# Oracle SQL Include a column to display without adding it in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, case-insensitive

I'm trying to find all case variation duplicates on the user table:

```
SELECT LOWER(EMAIL), COUNT(EMAIL) 
    FROM USERS
    GROUP BY LOWER(EMAIL)
    HAVING COUNT (LOWER(EMAIL)) >= 3;
```

Result would be similar to:

```
Emails                   Count (number of duplicates)
bob@example.com          3   
john.smith@example.com   3 
blah@example.com         4 
james.smith@example.com  3
```

The problem is that I need the ID of each email, how would I achieve that?  I can't simply add it to the SELECT statement because of the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT **ID**, LOWER(EMAIL), COUNT(EMAIL) 
    FROM USERS
    GROUP BY **ID**, LOWER(EMAIL)
    HAVING COUNT (LOWER(EMAIL)) >= 3;
```

The above would look for duplicated email **and** ID, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [analytic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) [`count()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions039.htm) for this, in an in-line view:

```
SELECT ID, EMAIL, LOWER(EMAIL), HOW_MANY
FROM (
  SELECT ID, EMAIL, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LOWER(EMAIL)) AS HOW_MANY
  FROM USERS
)
WHERE HOW_MANY >= 3
ORDER BY ID;

        ID EMAIL                          LOWER(EMAIL)                     HOW_MANY
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
         1 bob@example.com                bob@example.com                         3 
         2 Bob@example.com                bob@example.com                         3 
         3 BOB@example.com                bob@example.com                         3 
         4 john.smith@example.com         john.smith@example.com                  3 
         5 John.smith@example.com         john.smith@example.com                  3 
         6 JOHN.smith@example.com         john.smith@example.com                  3 
         7 blah@example.com               blah@example.com                        4 
         8 BLAH@example.com               blah@example.com                        4 
         9 blAH@example.com               blah@example.com                        4 
        10 BLah@example.com               blah@example.com                        4 
        11 james.smith@example.com        james.smith@example.com                 3 
        12 James.smith@example.com        james.smith@example.com                 3 
        13 JAMES.smith@example.com        james.smith@example.com                 3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12078/1). One of the nice things about analytics is that this only has to hit the table once.

Comment: Ohh cool, I've never heard of this before (I'm a newb at this). Gimmy a sec to try it out.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this is the best answer. It's a quick one too :). Runs well with large data. Your SQL Fiddle is also very helpful. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT U.*, COUNT(LOWER(EMAIL)) OVER (PARTITION BY (LOWER(EMAIL))) 
    FROM USERS U WHERE LOWER(EMAIL) IN (SELECT LOWER(EMAIL)
    FROM USERS
    GROUP BY LOWER(EMAIL)
    HAVING COUNT (LOWER(EMAIL)) >= 3);
```

Comment: I've tried similar query to that, but the problem is, I wouldn't be able to display the COUNT(EMAIL).